# /bin/sh akward behaviour

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am trying to create a run script with some simple flags using the `/bin/sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

set -eux

if [ "$DEBUG" = "true" ]; then
    debug="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=$SUSPEND,address=$DEBUG_PORT"
else
    debug=''
fi

serv="--server.port=${SERVER_PORT}"
prop="--spring.profiles.active=${PROFILES}"

all="${serv:-} ${prop:-}"

java "${debug:-}"-jar /opt/someJar.jar "${all:-}"
```

Now I have found some issues which I cannot explain neither find in google why it behaves like that.

1. note at `"${debug:-}"-jar` there is not space. When I put a space then application breaks and says "java cannot find or load the Main class". When I remove the space it works as expected.
2. I have two variables `serv` and `prop`. If I put those two as `"${serv:-}" "${prop:-}"` at the end of the java command then those two arguments are passed separately in the application. But when I put the `"${all:-}"` then from the exception rising in java I can see that those two are concatenated.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1234--spring.profiles.active=some-profile"
```

but because of the `set -eux` it prints

```bsh
+ java -jar /opt/someJar.jar --server.port=1234 --spring.profiles.active=some-profile
```

which is what I actually want.

If I did not provide enough info for any reason I can provide more.
What I try to achieve is to understand why it behaves that way and how can I use `/bin/sh` for some simple scripts like this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stéphane mentioned using `$@` as an array in plain shell. Here's one way to do it:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

set -eux
set --      # clear cmdline params

if [ "$DEBUG" = "true" ]; then
    set -- "-Xdebug" "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=$SUSPEND,address=$DEBUG_PORT"
fi

# specify the jar file
set -- "$@" -jar /opt/someJar.jar

# add the port and profile
set -- "$@" "--server.port=${SERVER_PORT}" 
set -- "$@" "--spring.profiles.active=${PROFILES}"

# and run it
java "$@"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! it worked just fine!

Answer (score 2):

`sh` has no arrays (other than `"$@"`, the array of positional parameters).

In:

```
java "${debug:-}"-jar /opt/someJar.jar "${all:-}"
```

`java` is only being passed 3 arguments (beside `java` itself).

the last one will contain something like `--server.port=1234 --spring.profiles.active=some-profile` with a space embeded in it while you intended to pass two arguments: `--server.port=1234` and `--spring.profiles.active=some-profile`.

A *scalar* (as opposed to *array*) variable like `$all` in `sh`, can only contain one value.

Instead, you can use the `"$@"` array as [Glenn has shown](/a/600592) (which also has my preference as mingling with `$IFS` and `noglob` is very messy) or you can instead tell the shell to *split* the contents of a variable upon expansion by setting the `$IFS` variable to the delimiter, and leave the parameter expansion unquoted (after also disabling globbing as globbing is also done by default upon unquoted parameter expansions).

For `$IFS`, you'd want to pick a character that cannot occur in the arguments, and if you want to preserve empty arguments, that character cannot be SPC, TAB, nor NL (all 3 happen to be in the default value of `$IFS`).

In your case however, it looks like you want an empty `$serv` for instance to result in no corresponding argument when `$serv` is empty (as opposed to one empty argument), so a whitespace `$IFS` is probably a better idea. NL is probably a good choice as it's unlikely to be found in your arguments here:

```
serv="--server.port=${SERVER_PORT}"
prop="--spring.profiles.active=${PROFILES}"
IFS="
" # newline character only
all="${serv:-}${IFS}${prop:-}"
set -o noglob # disable glob

java ... /opt/someJar.jar $all
```

You'd need to do something similar for `$debug`.

You can skip the `set -o noglob` if you can guarantee none of the arguments will contain wildcard characters nor braces nor backslashes.

Note that the `xtrace` output of your shell is a bit misleading. It gives a representation of the list of arguments passed to the command by outputting them raw and separated by SPC characters. What that means is that from that we can't differentiate the SPC characters that are part of arguments from the one which are output by `xtrace` to separate the arguments.

Some other shells are more helpful there in that they output quotes around the arguments when there is such ambiguity.

Compare the output of `set -x; printf "<%s>\n" foo "bar baz"` when interpreted by a few different shells:

```
$ dash -c 'set -x; printf "<%s>\n" foo "bar baz"'
+ printf <%s>\n foo bar baz
<foo>
<bar baz>
$ bosh -c 'set -x; printf "<%s>\n" foo "bar baz"'
+ printf <%s>\n foo bar baz
<foo>
<bar baz>
$ bash -c 'set -x; printf "<%s>\n" foo "bar baz"'
+ printf '<%s>\n' foo 'bar baz'
<foo>
<bar baz>
$ ksh -c 'set -x; printf "<%s>\n" foo "bar baz"'
+ printf '<%s>\n' foo 'bar baz'
<foo>
<bar baz>
```

Your `sh` seems to be in the `dash`/`bosh` category. See how their `+ printf <%s>\n foo bar baz` xtrace output make you think `printf` is being passed 3 `foo`, `bar`, `baz` arguments while in fact it is being passed two arguments: `foo` and `bar baz`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I actually understood more than I expected on why this thing happened.! A side note. the /bin/sh I am using is the most basic one as it is provided by a -slim version of docker. I will be going with @glenn answer tho as I will have to add more stuff later on and I cannot guarantee that I will not have expandable arguments.